# play framework 100% cpu

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a script that starts and stops my play application from cron. The trouble is the app is slow and always eating 100% CPU. I think its because of the way its started as I dont seem to observer it when I start it manually. By manually I mean typing start then hitting ctrl-D when prompted as directed.
As this is a computer I have started thinking that some operations could maybe be automated and not require my input and so I have made a script that trys to start it but obviously i wont be there for the ctrl-D part... I have started it as:

nohup /home/play/play-2.1.3/play "start -Dhttp.port=80" &

which works but its always eating 100% cpu and slow

can it be scripted or will I always be a slave to the machine and hqve to start it as described in the doc with me physically at the terminal

thanks

Comment: How many times are you starting and stopping this app?! shouldn't it be so infrequent as to not matter?

Comment: Sorry your right, my mistake, scripts arnt needed and I'll start all program's interactively.

Comment: But the 100% CPU issue is a real problem that someone should look in to, I'm not suggesting that you ignore it. However I would script it all though if it was a bother at all, even two commands can be simplified into one call to a script.

Answer (score 0):

We won't know why your app is slow, it may be caused by its logick not framework itself.

When you starting app with play console it's still compiles the project as de facto `play start` is not a production stage. Instead you can create [**`dist`**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist) version of your app, it contains bash script, so you can just create a shortcut to it on your desktop, after clicking it will start the app, and after closing this terminal window it will stop. Like a "normal" application.

Optionally you can even go further and create small graphical application, which will have buttons for starting/stopping the Play app, all depends on you.

Comment: if its the logic why does starting it like the doc says not cause the spinning CPU - your suggestion also recommends that i be there to start it with a mouse or something, i needs to be able to be scripted

Comment: the doc says use 'start' for production not dist "https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/Production"

Comment: however that doc talks about a 'stage' command to get around the prblem of interactivity si i will look at that

Comment: Use `dist` instead of `stage` as the last one sometimes is buggy... BTW you didn't mention how exactly you want to start... do you mean on running on system startup? so you should tell us which system do you use at least

Comment: can you point me to the doc on 'dist' as I need to start it on port 80

Comment: i think dist is for play 2.2 im using 2.1 this page http://alvinalexander.com/scala/play-framework-deploying-application-production-server seems to say to write a script the same as i have that nohups the start command for 2.1 but that ALWAYS results in 100% cpu

Comment: i really need the doc?

Comment: ok i ran dist and it worked apart from now my bootstrap glyphs dont display... any ideas?

Comment: check the paths and if files exists within the browser

Comment: the html still contains the correct path but the png icons are not created anywhere in the dist zip - these png are treated differently to /assets and are specified by the bootstrap.css...
can anyone help?

Comment: Describe it as a new question with samples